# Set secondary receiver in PayPal Chained Payment after the initial transaction

Tags: paypal

I'm running a service whereby customers seek the services of 'freelancers' through our web platform. The customer will make a 'bid' which is immediately taken from their accounts as security. Once the job is completed, the customer marks it as accepted and the bid gets distributed to the freelancer(s) as a reward.

After initially storing these rewards in the accounts of the freelancers and relying on MassPay to sort out paying them later, I realised that your business needs to be turning over at least £5000/month before MassPay is switched on.

Instead, I was referred to Delayed Chained Payments in PayPal's Adaptive Payments API. This allows the customer to pay the primary receiver (my business) before the payment is later triggered to be sent to the secondary receivers (the freelancers).

However, at the time that the customer initiates this transaction, you must understand that nobody yet knows who will receive the reward. So, before I program this whole Adaptive Payments system, is it even *possible* to change or add the secondary receivers after the customer has paid?

If not, what can I do?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I'm into the same problem.

Comment: I didn't, no. I just used two simple payments in the end because I implemented an online wallet to hold people's money.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the adaptive payments api to invoke several implicit payments.